# javascript - save data in local storage problem

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have an exercise, a user needs to login to my site(with email and his id) and then I save their details as an object in local storage, the user has the option to choose a template for the site from a number of options. The exercise is that each user who logs in will see the template he has chosen and not something else.

I Successfully saving the user in local storage as an array of objects as follows:

```
[
{email: a@b.com, id: 123456},{email: c@b.com, id: 789456}...
]
```

My problem is with getting the ID from the currently logged in user and putting it in a new array in local storage with the template they chose
I expect to get something like this:

```
[
{id:userID, template:userTemplate}
]
```

Then every time a user logs in to the site I access this array and take the template he chose and change the site accordingly.
As a matter of fact, I do not yet have a written code for this, so I ask here

Comment: Please read the ["How do I ask?" Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly save its credentials in Localstorag by storing them in an object and stringifying them to save in localstorage with [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem). setItem accepts a key and value to be saved.

```
let email= "khan@hotmail.com";
let id= "123";

let credObj = [
  {
   "email": email,
   "Id": id
  }
];

let objStr = JSON.stringify(credObj);

localStorage.setItem("userCreds",objStr)
```

Access the localstorage using [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) along with key:

```
let userCred= localStorage.getItem('userCreds');
JSON.parse(userCred);
```